# First Order Difference Equations

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to solve this first order difference equation. I usually go through the usual avenue (eigenvalues of homogeneous function then eigenvectors then solution) but here I don't know what I can do to get $y$ and $x$ power $1$ so that it becomes a system of two equations and two unknowns.

$x_{t+1}=-x_{t}+2x_{t}^{2}$

$y_{t+1}=-2x_{t}^{2}-y_{t}$

Comment: Hint: I would start by adding the two equations ...

Comment: can you give me more help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a solution, just some ideas i threw around which resulted in interesting results

We have that:

$$ x_{t+1} + y_{t+1} = -x_t - y_t $$

Let $Df = f_{x+1} - f_{x} $

$$ Dx + Dy = -2(x+y)$$

$$ u = x+y$$

(by linearity)

$$ Du = -2u$$

Assume that $u = a^t$ for some a. We find the a by noting

$$ a^{x+1} - a^t = -2a^t \rightarrow a - 1 = -2 \rightarrow a = -1 $$

Thus it follows that

$$ x+y = C_1 (-1)^t$$

Now for the second equation we can observe a very close solution. Recall

$$ x_{t+1} = - x_t + 2 x_t^2 $$

It follows then that

$$ Dx = 2x(x-1) $$

Consider the simpler

$$ Dx = x(x-1) $$

If we assume $x = 2^{g(x)}$ then

$$ Dx = 2^{g(x+1)} - 2^{g(x)} = 2^{g(x)}(2^{Dg}-1) $$

if $Dg = g \rightarrow g = C_1 2^t$ thus we have that

$$ x = C_1 2^{C_2 2^{t}} $$

So something closely related to that is what you seek.